# Arabic characters from jsp to java

Tags: java, jsp

In my jsp page I have this code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

```
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 // ... css + js
</head>
<body>

<%  request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");%>
<form action="AddPerson" name="addPerson"
        accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">

...
</form>
</body>
```

When I submit, the arabic characters are correctly displayed:
[image]

Here for the name we have : فهد, that what I want.

But in the java class, when I try to display the name I get:
ÙÙØ¯
In java:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
...
String name = req.getParameter("name");
System.out.println("name: " + name);
...
}
```

I don't know why, any suggestion?

Comment: So the problem is with the Java code, but you've shown us the HTML and JSP instead.  If you want help finding a problem, it's best if you show us the code that _has_ the problem, not the code that _doesn't_ have it.

Comment: `when I try to display the name ` you mean System.out.println or what? as @DawoodibnKareem said, problem is probably in java code, so try yo add it here

Comment: You should post only relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I found is to add a filter in web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```